# HTTParty X-Correlation_Id

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm trying to figure out HTTParty.  I have an endpoint I need to post to.

It won't let me post without setting an X-Correlation-Id according to the Swagger documentation.

I can't see an option in HTTParty to do this.

my current connection attempt is:

```
uuid =  SecureRandom.uuid
url = 'http://localhost:8720/v1/bla'
conn = HTTParty.post(url, body: body.to_json, headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json','Authentication' => "Token #{uuid}"})
```

I keep get an error response from the API stating the X-Correlation-Id is a mandatory field.  Is there something obvious I'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop it into your `headers` hash as another entry, the same way you've done for `'Content-Type'` and `'Authentication'`.

Headers which start with `X` tend to be custom ones, and so you won't find something built in to most HTTP clients for it, but they all support arbitrary headers like this.

Comment: I got completely confused.  {'X-Correlation-ID': uuid} worked.  Thnak you